# Using same JavaScript library across multiple components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am writing a Vue SPA with a simplified structure as follows:

App

|-Component 1

|-Component 2

|-Component 3

In each of these 3 components, I need to use a single imported JavaScript library. Currently each of these components imports the library on their own. However, the library is big, resulting in a large amount of memory use. What's the simplest way to import the library once and use it across my 3 components?

Comment: `However, the library is big, resulting in a large amount of memory use` are you sure about that? Most builders like Webpack and Parcel should be able to optimize this issue away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was unclear in my original details. The problem isn’t in loading the library itself, but rather in building an “analyzer” object that the library uses for certain analyses. 

My original plan was to initialize the analyzer in the main App.vue and bind the analyzer to the components. I wasn’t able to do so (for reasons I think may be clear to me now) so I went with my current approach. If my original plan is the correct way to go, I think I can manage to implement it now.

Comment: Ah. If you **measured** the generation of your analyzer object as slow and heavy (very strong emphasis meant here: you need to **MEASURE IT** with dev tools), then you could make your own library: in something like `analyzer.js`, simply create the object and `export` it. You can then import it wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm still new to this to be honest. The only reason I noticed was because firefox would spike 1GB with the tab

Comment: No problem =) -- As for Firefox jumping in RAM, it is indeed weird. Try to use the [Dev Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), particularly the [memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Memory) one. Good luck!

Comment: As for your question, I was trying to find a good duplicate target on Stack Overflow but couldn't find one. Let's keep discussing and identity your issue, see if we can make it a reference!

Comment: Thanks again for the help. The builder function from the library I'm using is an asynchronous function, so I had many problems in trying to export/import the script. Eventually I went with the solution I described above; First I buily the object in the main Vue, then sent it to each of the children. Luckily my component tree doesn't run too deep, so it's not a problem managing the flow of data.